# How to extract only pictures from html directories

Tags: filesystem

I have over 200 html files, each containing a png format picture, stored on my harddisk.

How can I extract those pictures into a separate folder easily?

Comment: Where are the pictures stored? They can't be embedded in the HTML file, the pictures must be referenced, either to a local png file or in the web.

Comment: I am sure you mean 'complete webpages', as when you save these in your browser, you gain both a `.html` file and a `_files` folder; it is the later that actually contains any images.

Comment: Do you need to keep any of the hierarchy info (that is, names of folders that pictures currently exist in)?  Do you care if a solution is command-line or GUI-based?

Answer (score 3):

When you save a *complete webpage* in your browser, you will have the html file, for example, `Mik.html` and its accompanying objects (js and pictures etc) in a file called, for example, `Mik_files`. Obviously, what you want is in those associated folders and **not** actually within the html file.

What I do is use the following script, which, in this case, finds all the `.png` images in the accompanying `_files` folders saved with the html pages. The images are moved to the directory you choose, although it must exist. The script can be modified as you wish-I have used two positional parameters `$1` and `$2` so you can choose which directory to target (`$1`) and where to copy the files that are found (`$2`). Run `chmod u+x` it to make it executable. You could add another positional parameter if you don't want it to just find `.png` files each time.

As an example, if it is not in your `~/bin`, you could call it with:

```
./scriptname.sh $HOME/Downloads $HOME/Documents
```

The contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -type f -iname '*.png' -print0 | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' f
do 
    mv -- "$f" "$2"  
done

exit 0
```